# this verb in past perfect "had stepped " can we know the exact moment this action began

Tags: past-tense

The movie was "Beach house" which got released via New line cinema in 1980. The rest? Well, it did not turn out quite that way...

Because there were so many scenes where live music  was supposed to be playing(courtesy of the on-screen band which was Adam Roth, Chris Phillips and Jonathan Paley, all the songs had to be recorded first.

The problem was, they did the demos  in a not-so-great studio in Boston with not a whole lot of attention to the performances . And from my perspective as Musical Director and composer, NO CLICK, this made things a little complicated.

Once the shooting had finished. I started cue-ing the scenes and discovered right away if there was gonna be a genuine push to get these songs on the radio, every song in the movie would have to be rerecorded it twice . So what's in the film is only in the film and what's on the Adam Roth and his band of men album, is what we recorded for radio.
The main band for this stuff was Adam, Rick, Charlie and me(C P Roth).

Once the film was finished and released, one of the young producers of the film **had stepped** in as Adam's manager

Can we know the exact moment the young producer became Adam's  manager after the band rerecorded the demo or before  . I think after should be the answer but I am not sure

I ve tried to summarize all main events of the text

recordings the demos first

sounding bad

end  of shooting (film)

```
           new manager first solution
```

rerecorded the demos

```
           new manager  second solution
```

film released

Comment: All we know is that one of the young producers of the film stepped in after it was finished and released.

Comment: but I don't understand , normally  the event written in  past perfect takes place before the event written in past simple why is it the contrary here . Really don't understand????

Comment: **Once** [after] the film **was** finished and released, one of the young producers of the film **had** stepped in as Adam's manager

Comment: so why past perfect  happened after the event written in past simple

Comment: had stepped is past perfect isn't it?

Comment: You're right to be confused. "Once the film was finished and released, one of the young producers of the film had stepped in as Adam's manager." What? You can't say "Once [after] X happened, Y *had* happened." You could say, "*Before* X happened, Y had happened." But I don't know if that's what the original writer meant, because the grammar doesn't make any sense.